# WooCommerce get product attributes with given product ID

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get the attributes from a product with a given ID stored in the URL. I need to get the title from the product which has the specific product_id.

This is what i have currently:

URL: http ://www.[asite].com/**?id=5**

I can already get the variable stored in the url like this:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]); ?>
```

So I have the product ID. But how can I get the product title from the product that has this ID?

```
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
get_product($id);
```

Something that would look like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) function?

```
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"]);
echo get_the_title( $id );
```